# Using arrays to compare table column values

Tags: arrays, sas

I have the following data in tableA and tableB.

Table A with column:TXNID, DUMPDT

Table B with column:TXNID, DUMPDT

I need to compare the TXNID in these two tables A and B and then if the TXNID doesnt exist in table B then i need to update table B with the missing TXNID. TXNID is a character column and contains upto 50 characters length, DUMPDT is a dt column with date type format with up 8 character length (format DATETIME22.3 / informat DATETIME22.3)

I was thinking of using Arrays since the TABLE A which is the source table could have varying # of rows in it from time to time so I really don't know how many rows will be in table A that i have to take and compare with TABLE B.

I currently have the following code but it does not seem to be working to well, sorry I am new to SAS so please forgive my errors, which I am sure i have made, i tried using a multi demensional array:

```
       data work.tableA;
       set tableA;
       array TXNID[*, 1] $ 50 ;
       run;

       data work.tableB;
       set tableA;
       array TXNID[*, 1] $ 50 ;
       run;
```

I am assuming I will have to use some kinda of do loop to compare the values as long as there are values present in both table A and table B in the TXNID columns

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use SQL to solve this. Here we are getting all the TXNID that are existing in tableA but not in tableB and inserting them into tableB.

```
proc sql;
INSERT INTO work.tableB
select a.TXNID, a.DUMPDT
from work.tableA a
where a.TXNID not in (select TXNID from work.tableB);
quit;
```

Comment: Thanks Dannmate for your suggestion, i will give this a try and let you know how it goes